# get certain number of rows using all id´s IN sentence

Tags: mysql

I have the next query:

```
SELECT a.id, a.brand_id
FROM articles a
WHERE a.deleted=0 AND a.brand_id IN (5,6)
LIMIT 4
```

How can I get 4 articles from all the brand_id's named at the IN sentence? For example, I would like to get 2 articles from brand_id=5 and 2 articles from brand_id=6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `union all`

```
( 
 SELECT a.id, a.brand_id
 FROM articles a
 WHERE a.deleted=0 AND a.brand_id = 5  limit 2
)
union all
(
  SELECT a.id, a.brand_id
 FROM articles a
 WHERE a.deleted=0 AND a.brand_id = 6 limit 2 
)
```

**UPDATE** , this could be achieved using m-per-group logic and one way would be as -

Consider the table

```
mysql> select * from articles ;
+------+----------+---------+
| id   | brand_id | deleted |
+------+----------+---------+
|    1 |        5 |       0 |
|    2 |        6 |       0 |
|    3 |        2 |       0 |
|    4 |        4 |       1 |
|    5 |        5 |       0 |
|    6 |        5 |       1 |
|    7 |        5 |       0 |
|    8 |        6 |       0 |
|    9 |        4 |       0 |
|   10 |        4 |       0 |
|   11 |        4 |       1 |
|   12 |        6 |       0 |
|   13 |        5 |       1 |
|   14 |        5 |       0 |
+------+----------+---------+
```

So with the query below will return n-per-group as

```
select 
id, 
brand_id 
from ( 
   select   
   id, 
   brand_id, 
   @r := if(@brand = brand_id,@r+1,1) as row_num, 
   @brand:= brand_id 
   from articles,(select @r:=0,@brand:='')rr  
   where 
   brand_id in (4,5,6) 
   and deleted = 0 
   order by brand_id
)x 
where x.row_num <=2 limit 6;

+------+----------+
| id   | brand_id |
+------+----------+
|    9 |        4 |
|   10 |        4 |
|    1 |        5 |
|    5 |        5 |
|    2 |        6 |
|    8 |        6 |
+------+----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So here the limit will be always number of items inside `IN` clause * 2

Comment: I am going to have 10 - 30 id´s at the IN sentence. Is there any other easier way?

Comment: I dont think there is any easy way for limiting data within in clause. May be some in SO may have a better idea.

Comment: @FernandoSantiago Of course there's a way but consider providing an sqlfiddle of same.

Comment: @Abhik Chakraborty that's an awesome query. I already test it and works like a charm! Also it is faster than your previous approach. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.id, a.brand_id
FROM articles a
WHERE a.deleted=0 AND a.brand_id=5
LIMIT 2
UNION ALL
SELECT a.id, a.brand_id
FROM articles a
WHERE a.deleted=0 AND a.brand_id=6
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: I am going to have 10 - 30 id´s at the IN sentence. Is there any other easier way?